# Move values and delete them after transfer

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. First is 'orders' and second is 'old_orders' what I am trying to do is after pressing button all values from table 'orders' should go into table 'old_orders' and after transfer values in table 'orders' should be removed. For now I can just move values but I don't know how to delete them after that. Below is my code

```
INSERT INTO old_orders (name)
    SELECT name
    FROM orders WHERE id=$id");
```

Comment: Perhaps you really want a `delete` trigger on `orders`.

Comment: If you need to delete all the orders in that table, you can use `TRUNCATE TABLE orders` instead of `DELETE` them. It is the fastest way to clear the table.

Comment: Why would you do this? It just seems like a bad idea.

Comment: *now I can just move values* No, you copy them.

Comment: @astentx *you can use `TRUNCATE TABLE orders` instead of DELETE them. It is the fastest way to clear the table.*. No. Pay attention - `orders.id` is used for rows identifying. If `id` is autoincremented PK then `TRUNCATE` will reset autoincremented counter to 1.

Comment: Your statement only copies one value (name) from orders to old_orders and for all rwos with the given id. Is it this what you want? If so, what's ablout `DELETE FROM orders WHERE id=$id` ?

Comment: @h.m.i.13 yes it works.... I'm dumb

Comment: @ascrkn I added an answer. There I added something that I realized now. If this is an anser for you, I would be glad if you mark it as answer. Just try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement copies the entries (I think it's only one) with the given id to the new table.

To "move" the entries you have to delete them after copying.

This can be done by `DELETE FROM orders WHERE id=$id`.

Be careful: the way you do it, the entries can get new ids. To be sure the id is copied too, you have to change you statement to:

```
INSERT INTO old_orders (id, name)
    SELECT id, name
    FROM orders WHERE id=$id;
```